# How does Python guarantees all objects in a set are unique?

Tags: python, set

Python sets claim to store only unique elements. When adding an element to a set, an error is raised if the element does not return something on `hash`, therefore, I guessed a set acted as a dictionary with hashes of the element as the keys. but when I added 2 different elements with the same hash, both of them were added within the set:

```py
class Obj:
   def __init__(self, message, value):
      self.message, self.value = value

   def __hash__(self):
      return hash(self.message)

s = set([Obj("1", 1), Obj("1", 2)])
# set value is Obj("1", 1), Obj("1", 2)
```

How does Python consider 2 objects to be equal or not in a set?